# Symfony, ManyToMany refers to the owning side field which does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a @ManyToMany relation with two entities.

I have (short code)

```
class Photo
{

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="photos")
    */
    protected $users;
}

class User
{

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_photos")
    */
    protected $photos;
}


php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
-> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'MyBundle\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo' mapping is invalid:
* The association MyBundle\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo#users refers to the owning side field Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#photos which does not exist.
```

I looked in stack and i try somethings but i still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    class Photo
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="photo")
    */
    protected $users;
}
class User
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_photos")
    */
    protected $photos;
}
```